# При бинде параметров в Оракле в произвольном порядке неверный запрос

Tags: c#, oracle

Для примера, есть запрос INSERT со множеством колонок.
Если биндить параметры не по порядку, то подставятся неверные значения.
Делаю это дело таким образом:

```
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table(id, user_id, parent) VALUES(:id, :userId, :parentId)";
            command.Parameters.Add("userId", 5);
            command.Parameters.Add("parentId", parentId);
            command.Parameters.Add("id", 1);
```

Раньше я такого не замечал. Как исправить зависимость от порядка?

Comment: А какой провайдер используете?

Comment: А если указывать тип: `.Add("id", OracleType.Int32).Value = 1;` ?